# PhpMyAdmin: введенные в таблицу значения отражаются знаками вопроса

Tags: phpmyadmin, php, кодировка

Скажите, пожалуйста! Почему введенные значения в таблицу на кириллице, MySQL отображает знаком вопроса (?). Может дело в кодировке? Как мне быть?

Comment: Все происходит в PhpMyAdmin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У меня в phpmyadmin в данной директории myadmin/index.php есть основные настройки (там можно установить кодировку). Скорее всего, у вас кодировка cp1251_general_ci. В ручную можно поменять так:

```
ALTER TABLE table1 CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET cp1251_general_ci
ALTER TABLE table1 DEFAULT CHARACTER SET cp1251_general_ci
ALTER DATABASE database1 DEFAULT CHARACTER SET cp1251_general_ci
```

Comment: MySQL charset: UTF-8 Unicode (utf8)
MySQL connection collation: utf8_general_ci

Все эти настройки у меня и так установлены как на главной странице так и в разделе Operations, но ситуация не меняется:( Скажите, команды ALTER TABLE надо вводить в разделе SQL где вводишь "запросы"?

Answer (score 1):

Выставьте кодировку в `utf8` и будет вам счастье. На главной странице должно быть что-то типа

```
MySQL charset: UTF-8 Unicode (utf8)
MySQL connection collation: utf8_general_ci
```

Comment: MySQL charset: UTF-8 Unicode (utf8) MySQL connection collation: utf8_general_ci

Все эти настройки у меня и так установлены как на главной странице так и в разделе Operations, но ситуация не меняется